# JSoup extract the text from the table td which doesnt contains any html nodes

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a html string like this :

```
String html="<table><tbody>
<tr>
<td><p>ABC</p></td>
<td>DEF</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>GHI</p></td>
<td>MNO</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>";
```

I only need to extract the text which has no more child elements inside **td** tags.My current code returns me both text and html nodes.

```
Elements elements = doc.select("tbody > tr");
for (Element e : elements) {
    System.out.println(e.select("td").html());
}
```

But what I need as the out put is :

```
DEF
MNO
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this CSS selector:

```
tbody > tr > td:not(:has(*))
```

#### DEMO

http://try.jsoup.org/~K4qiK0SxQDeuhE9FvvmUDa3vKKI

#### DESCRIPTION

```
tbody  /* Select any tbody */
> tr   /* Select any tr directly under it */
> td   /* Select any td directly under it ... */
:not(:has(*)) /* ... not having any element */
```

The `*` operator matches only **elements**. A text node is not an element. It's just a kind of Node.

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
Elements elements = doc.select("tbody > tr > td:not(:has(*))");
for (Element e : elements) {
    System.out.println(e.select("td").html());
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
<td>DEF</td>
<td>MNO</td>
```

Comment: Nicely put, but pretty much the same as my solution. Good explanation too, so I vote +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear to me, if you want to just the the text of each `td` that is not port of a child of that `td`, or if you want to further exclude all tds that have children. Therefore you may have to adapt my solution a bit.

```
String html="<table><tbody>"
        +"<tr>"
        +"<td><p>ABC</p></td>"
        +"<td>DEF</td>"
        +"<td>DEF2<p>ABC</p></td>"
        +"</tr>"
        +"<tr>"
        +"<td><p>GHI</p></td>"
        +"<td>MNO</td>"
        +"<td>MNO2<p>GHI2</p></td>"
        +"</tr>"
        +"</tbody>"
        +"</table>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = doc.select("tbody > tr > td:matchesOwn(.+)");
for (Element e : elements) {
    System.out.println(e.text());
}
```

The above solution looks for td elements that have any own text, i.e. that  match the regular expression `.+` (at least one character).

If you want to further weed out the tds that contain children, you can do this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = doc.select("tbody > tr > td:matchesOwn(.+):not(:has(*))");
for (Element e : elements) {
    System.out.println(e.text());
}
```

This uses both, the `:has()` and the `:not()`pseudo selectors as explained in the [JSOUP Docs](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Try [`Element.child(int index)`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#child-int-) with `index = 0`.

```
Elements elements = doc.select("tbody > tr");
for (Element e : elements) {
    for (Element el : e.select("td")) {
        // el.child(0)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried. But It did not work. It gives me an error also.  `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`

Comment: then surround it with `try-catch` and check it is giving exception for all or just for the ones which do not have any child.